# SBOM Generation using Cyclonedx

Tags: hashcode

I tried to generate **SBOM** file for my python project using Cyclonedx. But the **hash value** is missing for the library. How to Generate **SBOM** with **hash value** using Cyclonedx or some other tool?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Generating an SBOM in CycloneDX format is super easy using [syft](https://github.com/anchore/syft/). Two easy steps:

1. install syft

```
brew tap anchore/syft
brew install syft
```

2. generate an sbom from your image or file system

```
syft file:/my-python-project -o cyclonedx-xml
```

Comment: I am using syft to generate the sbom file, the file type is spdx, and the cmd is syft 

    packages dir:{} -o spdx |tee ~xxx.spdx

and the issue is the spdx file missing some package version, how to get the whole info